# Made LinearLayout clickable but only get response on its padding and not on child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to make a LinearLayout clickable, and this layout contains two child views: a TextView and a View that forms an underline under the TextView. I have tried many solutions but non have worked.

The issue is that the clickable LinearLayout only responds when the user clicks on its padding, and not when the user clicks on the child views.

I want the whole linear layout to propagate a pressed state when the user clicks anywhere on the LinearLayout and its child views. Here is the relevant portion of my layout file (I have tried setting the child views to be clickable but that negates the entire region being clickable):

```
...
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/routineday_page_set1_weight_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/routineday_page_set1_weight_textview"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/set_weight_text_selector"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="260lbs"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/routineday_page_set1_weight_underline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/set_weight_underline"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I should add, the whole region is currently set to clickable, and all child views are responding when the user clicks on the padding of the LinearLayout. However, there is no click response when the user clicks on any of the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method of the LinearLayout. When the touchEvent is in the padding zone, intercept the events. Otherwise, propagate the events to the children.

For more information about android touch event handling, please read [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup).